# Append DateTime in jQuery (Json) to table

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I am a Beginner at JQuery(Json).I am not sure if it is possible or not to append DateTime to the Json table.I have a dropdown list.By selecting on a item its automatically load some data on table. For doing so I am trying a json function like this:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#departmentId").change(function () {

            var deptId = $("#departmentId").val();
            //$("#courseId").empty();
            var json = { departmentId: deptId };
            $("#table").empty();
            $("#table").append('<table class="table"><tr><th>Course Code</th><th>Name</th><th>Schedule Info</th></tr>');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("ViewAllScheduleByDept", "ClassSchedule")',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify(json),
                success: function (data) {

                    $.each(data, function (key, value) {

                        $("#table").append('<tr><td>' + value.Code + '</td><td>' + value.Name + '</td><td>' + value.RoomName + ',' + ***value.StartTime.toDateString() +*** ' </td></tr>');

                    });
                    $('#table').append('</table>');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

It Displays Code,Name and RoomName perfectly but if I add StartTime to append along with these three item, It shows nothing. Is there any possible way to convert DateTime right on the Json table-append?. If not then how can I do show date time along with Code,Name and room name on MVC Razor view.

Here is my Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult ViewAllScheduleByDept(int departmentId)
    {
        var schedules = GetAllSchedule();
        var scheduleList = schedules.Where(a => a.DepartmentId == departmentId).ToList();
        return Json(scheduleList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }

    private List<ViewSchedule> GetAllSchedule()
    {
        List<ViewSchedule> allViewSchedules = scheduleManager.ViewAllSchedule();
        return allViewSchedules;

    }
}
```

And Model:

```
public class ViewSchedule
{
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string RoomName { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }


}
```

Comment: Try without `toDateString` call on the StartTime property

Comment: Try with : `+ value.StartTime.toString() +`

Comment: `$('#table').append('</table>')` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Just to be clear on naming: there's no such thing as a "JSON table". JSON is a string, that is then converted to an object. The `data` argument to your success function is that converted object, not JSON. The table is HTML that you're creating from the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The json date your endpoint returned will be some thing like this. See the value of `StartTime` property.

```
[{
   "Code":"SomeCode",
   "Name":"Some Name",
   "StartTime" :"/Date(1472239122527)/"
}]
```

That is the Epoch representation of the DateTime value you had. The json serializer converted the date time value to it's corresponding unix epoch time (*the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970*).

But in your code you are trying to call the `toDateString()` method on that. `toDateString()` should be called on a Date object.

So convert this number to a valid Date object first and then call the `toDateString` method on that.

```
$.each(data, function (key, value) {

   var dateFormatted = new Date(parseInt(value.StartTime.substr(6))).toDateString();
   $("#table").append('<tr><td>' + value.Code
                   + '</td><td>' + value.Name 
                   + '</td><td>' + value.RoomName
                   + ',' + dateFormatted + ' </td></tr>');

});
```

Comment: Thanks, It works.If I want just Time not the date then where i need to change @Shyju

Comment: You can extract the time info from the Date object. Take a look at the mdn documentation on Date. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date